# Turkish letters in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, rds

I am using a free tier RDS database (mysql) in Amazon. I am having trouble with some Turkish letters like İ,ı,Ş etc. As you can see in below images, the character set is "utf8" and collation is "utf8_turkish_ci"

But when I insert some letters like İ, it gives I . Please let me know, how can I fix this problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're doing everything right. Furthermore, there are other non-Latin characters in your value that are represented correctly. Are you sure that's the data in the DB, and not just some poor representation of the character in your SQL client?  Try running the query from a terminal and see what you get.

Comment: hi @StevenMoseley. I am getting the same letters when I run the query from a terminal.

Comment: Well, sorry to say I'm not going to be much help, then.  May be an anomaly in MySQL or RDS.

Comment: Try posing your question to AWS support.  Be sure to repost their answer back here!